# Can't get my HTML Canvas to fit 90% of the screen. Tried multiple scripts

Tags: html, canvas, resize

Please help. I am a bit of a dinosaur when it comes to coding. I used to mostly do HTML and a little bit of Java years back, but I recently started making a site for my comedy group, and have had some issue. First, I made an interactive imagemap using flash, which I know decently well, only to discover I am out of touch and flash doesn't work on a lot of smartphones and i-pads. So then I converted the .fla to HTML5 using Adobe Animate CC. 
It seems to work fine, but I can't get the height and width to fit the screen (I want 85% width, and 90% height). I've looked on this site and seen a few different answers, that I have tried, but each time I can't get it to work. Please help.

Here is a link to my testpage: 
www.standupseoul.com/test1.html

you should be able to the source, as well as the javascript.

### (yes, the height and width are specified right now, but when I alter, i can't get the image to change size):

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS style file

```
.mycanvas {
    width: 90%;
    height: 85%;
}
```

and `class="mycanvas"` to your canvas element.

The image looks a bit stretched, you might want to find a higher-quality replacement.